# Error in passing geometry column to SQL query

Tags: oracle-spatial

When I execute the following query with a static table name it's working fine:

```
SELECT pe.structure_category_name,SDO_NN_DISTANCE(2),pe.bt_object_subid,
pe.bt_owning_node_id INTO v_sDPsct,v_saddDPdist,v_dpTypeNearSrvAdd,
v_sbtOwningNodeID FROM piper_equipment pe WHERE
SDO_NN(pe.shape,(unservedValue.shape),'sdo_batch_size=10',2) = 'TRUE' AND ROWNUM < 2 AND pe.bt_object_id = v_saddDPid
```

Here **unservedValue** is the data_record fetching through cursor.
I have to pass table name as variable , so I have changed above query into the following:

```
stmt_piperequipment3 := 'SELECT pe.structure_category_name,SDO_NN_DISTANCE(2), 
pe.bt_object_subid,
pe.bt_owning_node_id INTO v_sDPsct,v_saddDPdist,v_dpTypeNearSrvAdd, v_sbtOwningNodeID 
FROM '||VWPIPERDATA||' pe WHERE
SDO_NN(pe.shape,(unservedValue.shape),''sdo_batch_size=10'',2) = ''TRUE'' AND
ROWNUM < 2 AND pe.bt_object_id = v_saddDPid';
execute immediate stmt_piperequipment3;
```

While executing above query it's giving following error

```
ORA-00904: "UNSERVEDVALUE"."SHAPE":invalid identifier.
```

My question is how to pass a shape into the string variable?

Comment: I noticed your question on an oracle forum. You might try on the spatial forum. I do know the minds there are quite capable of answering this type of question.  https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=76&start=15

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was not correct, sorry but I was misled by the term 'string variable'.
I thought that *unservedValue.shape* was actually a column. My bad.

One of the documentation [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm) is actually key to the solution anyway. Have you tried something like this:

```
stmt_piperequipment3 := 'SELECT pe.structure_category_name,SDO_NN_DISTANCE(2), 
pe.bt_object_subid,
pe.bt_owning_node_id INTO v_sDPsct,v_saddDPdist,v_dpTypeNearSrvAdd, v_sbtOwningNodeID 
FROM '||VWPIPERDATA||' pe WHERE
SDO_NN(pe.shape, :1 ,''sdo_batch_size=10'',2) = ''TRUE'' AND
ROWNUM < 2 AND pe.bt_object_id = v_saddDPid';
execute immediate stmt_piperequipment3 using unservedValue.shape;
```